# Angular datePicker with Selection Strategy when used in formGroup triggers twice

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm using [material date picker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#customizing-the-date-selection-logic) and linking it to FormGroup

The issue is when I try to update the `dateRange` FormGroup `this.dateRange.valueChanges.subscribe` is triggered twice , once with the last value of `dateend` and once with the new value.

here's a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zgm3ld?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdate-range-picker-selection-strategy-example.html,src%2Fapp%2Fdate-range-picker-selection-strategy-example.ts%3AL51) reproduction of the issue.

```
export class DateRangePickerSelectionStrategyExample implements OnInit {
  val: any = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dateRange.valueChanges.subscribe((formValue) => {
      this.val.push(formValue);
    });
  }
  dateRange: DateRangeForm = createDateRangeForm();
}
export interface DateRangeForm extends FormGroup {
  start: Date | undefined;
  end: Date | undefined;
}

export function createDateRangeForm(): DateRangeForm {
  return new FormGroup({
    start: new FormControl(),
    end: new FormControl(),
  }) as unknown as DateRangeForm;
}
```

**html**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="example-form-field">
    <mat-label>{{ label }}</mat-label>
    <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="rangePicker" [formGroup]="dateRange">
        <input matStartDate placeholder="Début" formControlName="start" [min]="dateStart" [max]="dateEnd" [disabled]="inputDisabled" />
        <input matEndDate placeholder="Fin" formControlName="end" [min]="dateStart" [max]="dateEnd" [disabled]="inputDisabled" />
    </mat-date-range-input>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="rangePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-date-range-picker #rangePicker [disabled]="!inputDisabled">
        <mat-date-range-picker-actions *ngIf="action">
            <app-button class="btn" [theme]="'secondary'" [label]="'Annuler'" mat-button matDateRangePickerCancel></app-button>
            <app-button [theme]="'primary'" [label]="'Appliquer'" mat-raised-button color="primary" matDateRangePickerApply></app-button>
        </mat-date-range-picker-actions>
    </mat-date-range-picker>
</mat-form-field>
```

I would like to know how can I do to only triggers `valueChanges` only once when selection is finished (after that date-picker sets the right `datestart` and `dateend` ) ?

Answer (score 0):

Add (close) event to your mat-date-range-picker

```
<mat-date-range-picker (closed)="onClose()" #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
```

Comment: That only works if I change the date from the UI , but my real case can also do it programatically